# select a value from dropdown list via EXCEL VBA

Tags: html, excel

I have been searching for this answer, but I can't get it right to execute.
I can login to web page, then it pops up a new window. I need to select a value from drop-down list.
please help me on this.

#### HtmlElement

```html
<select name="fldcustval" onchange="fnsetBankName();fnSetCurrencyList();fnGetCustomer();displayDetails(this);">..</select>
```

#### My Attempts

I have tried this, but can't get it to work.

```html
ie.Document.getElementsByname("flducstval").Focus
ie.Document.getElementsByname("fldcustval").selectedindex=2 
-->(the second option in dropdown list)
ie.Document.getElementsByName("fldcustval").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

Comment: I assume the method `getElementsByName` would return multiple elements. Have you tried adding a watch and seeing what is returned within the VBA Editor?

You may have to specify an index such as:
`ie.Document.getElementsByName("flducstval")(0).Focus`

Comment: I will give a try at work next day. I wonder if i can use sendkeys to select the second option?

Comment: Is this web browser a control on the form or are you instantiating it in the code?

Comment: It is a web browser control on the form.

Comment: I failed in both ways(sendkeys andgetelementsbyname). I dont know why

Comment: Would it be possible to post some more code on what you are trying to do? The webpage might not have loaded before your code is executed.

Comment: Yeah, i figured that out. I wait for 8 seconds before executing the code.

Comment: Ie.document.getelementsbyname("flducstval")(0).Focus

Comment: If you've found a solution, please answer this question and mark it as the correct one. SO welcomes this so don't feel put off by it.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt find the answer. I just tried to type the code i used.

Comment: In the end, i have used sendkeys function.

Comment: I hope someone can help me on this